# WPF How to always select the 2nd column of selected row

Tags: c#, wpf

I got this event

```
private void dgvConfig_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridCellInfo info in dgvConfig.SelectedCells)
            {

                if (info.Column.Header.ToString() != "Car Name") continue;
                dgvConfig.CurrentCell = info;
                break;
            }
        }
```

I wanted the 2nd column of my selected row to always selected
ex.
table columns: Id, Car Name, Description
I selected a row by clicking the Description, the selected cell must automatically go to column index 2 (Car Name)

The code above worked fine but the problem is I also use it in a different table (table columns: Id, Chassis Name, Description) and it will require me to create multiple conditions since there is no Chassis Name column in Cars table

Comment: is this for UI purposes only?

Comment: Can't you check info.Column.DisplayIndex == 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
//handle the SelectionChanged event
private void dgvConfig_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
                                        SelectionChangedEventArgs e){
   //set the CurrentCell to the cell on the current row 
   //in the second column
   if(dgvConfig.Columns.Count > 1){
      dgvConfig.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dgvConfig.SelectedItem,
                                                   dgvConfig.Columns[1]);
   }
}
```